# TRESTRequest adds a trailing slash if last queryparameter is empty?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi's `TRESTRequest` component to make a POST request, and I have some query parameters in the URL. The `Resource`property of the `TRESTRequest`looks like this:

*index.php?operation={operation}&id={id}&test={test}*

The parameters `operation`, `id` and `test` parameters are `pkURLSEGMENT`.

The `BaseURL`property of the `TRESTClient` is of the form `https://example.com/myapi/v1/`.

Everything works fine if I set `test` to `1` or some other value, the requested URL is as expected:

*index.php?operation=foo&id=bar&test=1*

But if I set it to an empty string, the actual requested URL becomes

*index.php?operation=foo&id=bar&test=/*

Why does the slash get added, and how can I prevent it? Right now I'm resorting to using `0` instead of an empty value, but for future reference it would be good to know how to use an empty value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there's no strict definition for term *URL segment* and from its name you might deduce it refers to just any part of URL, it usually represents segment of URL path and should therefore be called *path segment*.

For instance, [the definition of UrlSegment in Angular router](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSegment) is

> A `UrlSegment` is a part of a URL between the two slashes. It contains a path and the matrix parameters associated with the segment.

`TCustomRESTRequest.DoApplyURLSegments` is responsible for the behavior you observe. Check out its implementation.

But the segments in your code represent values in query string. [`pkQUERY`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/REST.Types.TRESTRequestParameterKind) was designed for those kind of parameters. `pkQUERY` was introduced in [Delphi 10.3 Rio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/What%27s_New#Improvements_for_REST). In case you're using an older version you will have to resort to a workaround:

- Use dummy value (your current workaround).
- Change the order of parameters or append dummy parameter at the end so that the last parameter is never blank.
- Use `pkGETorPOST` instead, but this will only work with `GET` method.
- Manage query string yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Now I recall reading about `pkQUERY` a few months ago, but unfortunately I'm using Delphi 10.2 so that's not an option. And using `pkGETorPOST` won't work since I'm sending the data as a `pkREQUESTBODY`, and the server won't accept a multipart body... I'll stick with my workaround until upgrading Delphi.